# SQL multiple left join as new columns performance

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have 3 tables :

**account**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Google |
| 2 | Apple |

**custom_field**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Phone |
| 2 | Email |

**custom_field_submission**

| id | custom_field_id | entity_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 555-444-333 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 111-111-111 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | google@goog.com |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | apple@apple.com |

**Expected result after query**

| id | name | Phone | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Google | 555-444-333 | google@goog.com |
| 2 | Apple | 111-111-111 | apple@apple.com |

I have a query like this :

```sql
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
phone.value as phone,
email.value as email

FROM account a

LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT custom_field_submission.value, custom_field_submission.entity_id
  FROM custom_field_submission
  WHERE custom_field_submission.custom_field_id = 1) AS phone 
ON phone.entity_id = a.id

LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT custom_field_submission.value, custom_field_submission.entity_id
  FROM custom_field_submission
  WHERE custom_field_submission.custom_field_id = 2) AS email 
ON email.entity_id = a.id
```

In the reality I have 20 custom fields for 10 000 accounts. Where I run the query It is very slow (3-4 seconds)

Do you have an idea to manage optimize this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cf.name = 'Phone' THEN cfs.value END) AS Phone,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cf.name = 'Email' THEN cfs.value END) AS Email
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN custom_field_submission cfs
    ON cfs.entity_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN custom_field cf
    ON cf.id = cfs.custom_field_id
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.name;
```

Comment: Thanks you ! Strangely it is little slower with few fields, but much faster with many fields. Greats ! 